# Drawing SVG on Kivy canvas

Tags: python, canvas, svg, kivy

I am new to Kivy.
i need to create a classic analog clock.

My Question is: how to draw svg graphics into kivy canvas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kivy master have now experimental SVG supports. It will be out in the 1.9.0.

See more at:

- https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/examples/svg/main.py
- https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/graphics/svg.pyx
- https://twitter.com/mathieuvirbel/status/513161191817220097

Comment: @tito - I'm also trying to display svg but in the end I want to display a chart. I found pygal that will output svg. Is there an easier way to display charts in kivy (simple lines/bar/ possibly a stock ticker chart)? I checked matplotlib and to create a backend seems like quite a bit of work. Is that the way you would go or should I wait for the SVG implementation? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

@incognick

There's no need to use any other libraries. Make a widget using Kivy itself.

To do this, first subclass kivy.widget.Widget, and then define a canvas with some kivy.graphics.Instruction in it.

[More detail here.](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.graphics.html)